# Chrome Flickering bug + Dragging tabs buggy

Tags: multiple-monitors, google-chrome, chromium

### Summary

Recently made the switch to ubuntu, mostly because I loved using WSL on windows for development work. (I'm a software engineer and freelance on the side)Honestly I LOVE ubuntu.Ok the meat of it:I have been able to fix most of the issues that I encounter.This one drives me crazy.I like using chrome, and this only happens with chrome.I have tried it chromium as well, and it doesn't happen with chromium (the flicker part)

I have screen recorded 2 bugs to show here.

### Screen flash/stretch bug

When grabbing the top bar of a window, when chrome is maximized, a glitch happens. It's almost like it instantaneously stretches across 2 displays. this does not happen with chromium, or firefox.In the video, it looks like the flash/stretch thing only happens every so often, but it actually happens every time. I believe my screen recorder was just missing it (frame rate missing the flash)I believe maybe chrome is "thinking" my screen is actually that wide for a split second before the actual calculation is completed. Hard to tell

### Popout tab bug

2: when grabbing a tab, it gets stuck on the edge of a monitor, and will not move to my middle monitor at all (I have 3)Also, If I move to fast, it will get stuck till I drag the mouse closer to it again. This part doesnt happen in chromium.You will also see by the video, that the tab assumes a rectangular shape, which is the same size as if it were just popped out of maximzied mode (called restore on windows, not sure if the terminology is different) But chrome will not allow the window to move off of the desktop's physical view) this happens in both chromium and in chrome. I'm assuming this is one of those times where "its a feature not a bug" but the first two are definitely bugs. lmao

I've tried digging around a bit for info, but it's a bit difficult to articulate what is happening into a google search.

I have not submitted a bug report, as I am hoping there is a known fix.

I have a post here on reddit with the [video](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ohtnu2/chrome_flickering_bug_dragging_tabs_buggy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)